# HTTPRequest.getSession returns a fresh session after session is invalidated

Tags: session, tomcat8

I have developed a web app currently hosted in tomcat 8.5.I5. I am trying to implement SSO with IDP and here I have used filters for this. After sucessful login I set the user name as following.

```
HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
httpSession.setAttribute(SESSION_USERNAME, subject);
```

When validating used the following code.

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String userName = (String) session.getAttribute(SSOHelper.SESSION_USERNAME);

 if (userName == null && request.getRequestURI().contains("dashboard.xhtml")) {
```

Logout is implemented as follwing

request.getSession().invalidate();

The problem is this only works for the first time. Second time it keeps on asking the login. Seems the session is created per requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues seems to be when you define the host name without a dot (.). For example I have used localhost for my testing. After adding a entry to hosts file with domain name malaka.com, and used to access the web app, issue was resolved.